# BeautifulSoup kills program on high demand of work

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm developing a Python script (https://github.com/BrunorpPaixao/lmfm4u) that is used to clean the text you get from Facebook when you ask them to send you all the messages you've ever sent/recieved.

It is working great for most of the files, but when i try and scan a giant text file, some minutes after staring at a frozen screen, I get a message on my terminal saying "killed", I think the problem comes from BeautifulSoup and its ability to load huge files.

The file structure is like this, although the original file is not indented:

```html
<div class="pam _3-95 _2pi0 _2lej uiBoxWhite noborder">
    <div class="_3-96 _2pio _2lek _2lel">Francisco Zacarias</div>
    <div class="_3-96 _2let">
        <div>
            <div></div>
            <div>eles nao deram respwan</div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="_3-94 _2lem">11/12/2017, 21:48</div>
</div>
<div class="pam _3-95 _2pi0 _2lej uiBoxWhite noborder">
    <div class="_3-96 _2pio _2lek _2lel">Francisco Zacarias</div>
    <div class="_3-96 _2let">
        <div>
            <div></div>
            <div>deve ter bugado ent</div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="_3-94 _2lem">11/12/2017, 21:48</div>
</div>
<div class="pam _3-95 _2pi0 _2lej uiBoxWhite noborder">
    <div class="_3-96 _2pio _2lek _2lel">Bruno Paixao</div>
    <div class="_3-96 _2let">
        <div>
            <div></div>
            <div>e usares nos pilares</div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="_3-94 _2lem">11/12/2017, 21:44</div>
</div>
<div class="pam _3-95 _2pi0 _2lej uiBoxWhite noborder">
    <div class="_3-96 _2pio _2lek _2lel">Bruno Paixao</div>
    <div class="_3-96 _2let">
        <div>
            <div></div>
            <div>é so dropares 5</div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="_3-94 _2lem">11/12/2017, 21:44</div>
</div>
<div class="pam _3-95 _2pi0 _2lej uiBoxWhite noborder">
    <div class="_3-96 _2pio _2lek _2lel">Bruno Paixao</div>
    <div class="_3-96 _2let">
        <div>
            <div></div>
            <div>e usas uma em cada pilar</div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="_3-94 _2lem">11/12/2017, 21:45</div>
</div>
```

Its a bunch of HTML code in a simple line which then I use BeautifulSoup to remove all the HTML tags, then use a regex to split the messages and finally, setting them correctly.

```
import re
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


regex = re.compile('\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4},.\\d{2}:\\d{2}')
CleanStartTime = time.time()
cleaned = BeautifulSoup(document, "lxml").get_text()
cleaned = cleaned.split(" ")
if(len(cleaned) < 290):
    print("Wrong type of file, please choose a facebook messenger history file.")
    quit()
else:
    for i in range(290):
        cleaned.pop(0)
cleaned =  " ".join(cleaned)
cleanedwregex = re.split(regex, cleaned)
listofdates = re.findall(regex, cleaned)
CleanEndTime = time.time()
print("HTML cleaned in " + str("%.2f" % (CleanEndTime - CleanStartTime)) + "seconds")

PrintStartTime = time.time()
gucciString = ""
for i in range(len(cleanedwregex) - 1):
    gucciString += listofdates[i] + " | " + cleanedwregex[i] + "\n"
```

and finally, the output looks like this:

```
11/12/2017, 21:44 | Bruno Paixaotens de matar os orcs
11/12/2017, 21:44 | Bruno Paixaoai
11/12/2017, 21:31 | Francisco Zacariaso que é que tenho de fazer aqui
11/12/2017, 21:31 | Francisco Zacarias
11/12/2017, 21:31 | Francisco Zacariascaro engenheiro do ips peço desculpa estar a incomodar mas nao sei o que fazer agora
```

I'm hoping to get some help on "BeautifulSouping" large files, I thought about checking the total amount of characters (some reached 58 million characters) and doing it in bits, appending to a final file, but before I try that, I'd like opinions from some of you.

If you want to check the full code, click the github link at the top, any help is really appreciated!

Comment: If you haven't already, you could comment out sections of your code to be certain that BeautifulSoup is running out of memory when cleaning the files. Then you can post that section specifically, along with an example file, so we can help you better.

Comment: @HS-nebula I commented everything but the "cleaned = BeautifulSoup(document, "lxml").get_text()" and it died, i guess the problem comes from BeautifulSoup itself, is it possible to increase its memory use? also, I'm using a crappy laptop in my intership, may that be the problem?

Comment: Possibly, but I think the issue is you calling `get_text()` on your `BeautifulSoup` object. Depending on how big the `document` is, it will take time to parse the full file. Instead, you should parse it by extracting the parts individually, you can see [here](https://github.com/lcdm-uiuc/info490-sp17/blob/master/notebooks/intro2smw.ipynb) and [here](http://www.compjour.org/warmups/govt-text-releases/intro-to-bs4-lxml-parsing-wh-press-briefings/) for references.

Comment: If the document is XML, you are best off using a SAX parser, because those do not build a DOM tree. The process of building a DOM tree out of very large input is what kills your script. In order to suggest something, a more complete input sample (i.e. one that reveals the document structure) is needed though.